# Prove that $a^4 \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ if $\space a \neq 5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $a^4 \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ if$ \space a \neq 5$

I've tried showing this by induction.

Clearly if $ a = 5$ then $ a \equiv 0 \bmod 5$

now if $a = 1$ then $a^4 - 1 = 0$ which is divisible by 5, so base case holds.

Then, the induction hypothesis, assume that it is true for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Now to show that it holds for the case where $a = k + 1$

I've tried this:

$a^4 - 1 = (a^2-1)(a^2+1)$

so $(k+1)^4 - 1 = ((k+1)^2 -1)((k+1)^2+1)$

the problem arises when I try to factorize $((k+1)^2 -1)((k+1)^2+1)$

how should i factorize it so that $(k^2 -1)(k^2+1)$ is a factor?

Comment: You could just plug in all 5 residue classes. No need for induction.

Comment: so for 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: $\textbf{Euler-Fermat's Little Theorem.}$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a standard way to use induction: it is equivalent to prove that $a^5 \equiv a \pmod 5$ for all $a$.  First, show that
$$
(a+1)^5 \equiv a^5 + 1^5 \equiv a^5 + 1 \pmod 5
$$
Then, use induction on $a$.

Answer (score 1):

For small modulus it is usually the fastest and simplest to check all cases. That would be $1,2,3,4 \pmod{5}$. Note that your question as stated is wrong. It works for all integer $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$. "$a = 5$" is not enough.

For larger modulus induction usually doesn't work either, instead you often need to prime factorize the modulus and use Euler's theorem that says $a^{φ(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ for any integer $a$ coprime to $n$. Euler's theorem cannot be proven by induction on $a$ either.